# How to know if any process is writting a file?

Tags: android, file

I have a service that notifies me when a new Screenshot file appears in the directory `Pictures/Screenshots`. The problem is that this file is being written by the screenshot process. How can I know when this process finished to write the file?

Comment: Have a look at FileObserver class.

Comment: It doesn't work in 6.0+

Comment: I'm guessing catlog is out so...lsof? Or...do you have root? This answer suggests replacing the libs so you can watch syscalls: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28326775/3981745 . I realize these aren't ideal but hope it helps.

Comment: Wich event number(s) is/are missing?

Comment: Sorry! You was completely right. I can get that events with `FileObserver`. It doesn't work with directories, but it works with files.

Comment: Ok, this is really odd. It seems that FileObserver doesn't work just in API 23 (M). It works for me in my Nougat phone, but it doesn't in Marshmallow one... Someone pointed this out here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189231#c30